# Problem resolving dependencies because of [organisation]

Tags: ant, ivy

In my ivysettings.xml, I have a url resolver with the following artifact resolver:

```
<artifact pattern="http://my-repo-server/my-repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
```

Any organisation that has a "." in its name fails to resolve (such as org.apache.struts#struts-core;1.3.5). I've come to the conclusion that the reason for the failure is that instead of going to

http://my-repo-server/my-repo/org/apache/struts/struts-core/1.3.5/struts-core-1.3.5.jar

it goes to

http://my-repo-server/my-repo/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.5/struts-core-1.3.5.jar

(Notice the "." instead of the "/" in the above urls)

Am I using the wrong type of resolver? Is my pattern wrong? How do I resolve an artifact with "." in the organization name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the ibibli resolver, but I had issues bringing in the dependencies of my published dependencies. So I found that if I set the m2compatible to true, and specify the ivy file, I can use the url resolver. I also am generating to pom file just in case I want to use maven some day.

```
<url name="artifactory" m2compatible="true">
   <ivy pattern="http://my-repo-server/my-repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
   <artifact pattern="http://my-repo-server/my-repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
   <artifact pattern="http://my-repo-server/my-repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" />
 </url>
```